# non-standard translations at HSE

Tags: discussion

अन्तवत्तु फलं तेषां तद्भवत्यल्पमेधसाम् |
देवान्देवयजो यान्ति मद्भक्ता यान्ति मामपि || 23||

is being translated as

[What is meant Bhagvad Gita 7.23?Isn't god one?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/55553/12489)

> "Men of small intelligence worship the demigods, and their fruits are limited and temporary. Those who worship the demigods go to the planets of the demigods, but My devotees ultimately reach My supreme planet"

whereas a neutral scholarly translation would be

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/7/verse/23

> BG 7.23: But the fruit gained by these people of little understanding is perishable. Those who worship the celestial gods go to the celestial abodes, while My devotees come to Me.

Is it possible to have some scholarly standards for citations,translations and arguments?

the word "demigod" in translations of Hindu scripture was virtually unknown until the 1970s and there has been no scholarly breakthrough to suggest "demigod" is a valid word to translate divine entities of Hinduism.

Can "community notes" be put on non-standard translations and alternative scholarly translations posted alongside?